# Convert vbs encrypted script to string

Tags: vbscript

I have a .vbe (.vbs)  file with encrypted script produced by screnc.
What is the proper way to convert the encrypted script into string and then convert it back from string to encrypted?

I think I should specify my question. I have created a vbs script. In order to protect it- I encoded it into vbe. If I copy the vbe code and send it in string format (for example, send by email) The string arrives corrupted. How should I handle the code so that I could safely send to other source? Great thanx in advance!

Comment: How did you sent your code with copy and paste on the body of your email or with attachement with extension .vbe or in .txt ?

Comment: I send it with copy and paste on the body of email. I also tried pastebin services but as the result the code is corrupted. That is why I mentioned in my question that may be it would be usefull to convert it first to string?

Comment: Try to copy it in a text file and send it with attachement

Answer (score 3):

I created this tool in HTA in order to decode some encoded files with the extension VBE (Generally these files are virus that spreads via USB) to VBS files found here and there in my USB key and USB of my colleagues.

[image]

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Encode VBS2VBE & Decode VBE2VBS Files © Hackoo © 2012</title>
<HTA:APPLICATION
  APPLICATIONNAME="Encode VBS2VBE & Decode VBE2VBS Files © Hackoo © 2012"
  ID="Encode & Decode Files"
  ICON="Explorer.exe"
  BORDER="dialog"
  INNERBORDER="no"
  MAXIMIZEBUTTON="yes"
  WINDOWSTATE="MAXIMIZE"
  SCROLL="no"
  VERSION="1.0"/>
  <bgsound src="&#104;&#116;&#116;&#112;&#58;&#47;&#47;&#104;&#97;&#99;&#107;&#111;&#111;&#46;&#97;&#108;&#119;&#97;&#121;&#115;&#100;&#97;&#116;&#97;&#46;&#110;&#101;&#116;&#47;&#112;&#105;&#114;&#97;&#116;&#101;&#115;&#46;&#109;&#112;&#51;" loop="&#105;&#110;&#102;&#105;&#110;&#105;&#116;&#101;"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" title="design_encoder" href="&#0104;&#0116;&#0116;&#0112;&#0058;//&#0104;&#0097;&#0099;&#0107;&#0111;&#0111;&#0046;&#0097;&#0108;&#0119;&#0097;&#0121;&#0115;&#0100;&#0097;&#0116;&#0097;&#0046;&#0110;&#0101;&#0116;/&#0100;&#0101;&#0115;&#0105;&#0103;&#0110;&#0095;&#0101;&#0110;&#0099;&#0111;&#0100;&#0101;&#0114;&#0046;&#0099;&#0115;&#0115;"/>
<style>
Label
{
 color : white;
 font-family : "Courrier New";
}
input.button {  background-color : #EFEFEF;
                color : #000000; cursor:hand;
                font-size: 11px; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }
</style>
</head>

<script language="VBScript">
Sub Window_OnLoad
  'CenterWindow 730, 540
End Sub
Sub CenterWindow(x,y)
        window.resizeTo x, y
        iLeft = window.screen.availWidth/2 - x/2
        itop = window.screen.availHeight/2 - y/2
        window.moveTo ileft, itop
End Sub 

Sub OnClickButtonCancel()
  Window.Close
End Sub

Sub Decode_Textarea
Const FOR_READING = 1, FOR_WRITING = 2, BOOL_CREATION = True, BOOL_TRISTATETRUE = -1, BOOL_NO_CREATION = False
Set objFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set Ws = CreateObject("wscript.Shell")
code = txtBody.value
Set F = objFso.OpenTextFile("DecodeMe.vbs",2,True)
F.writeline "Msg=" & code & ""
F.WriteLine "Set objFso = CreateObject(""Scripting.FileSystemObject"")"
F.WriteLine "objFso.OpenTextFile(""DecodedFile.txt"",2,True).WriteLine Msg"
F.Close
If objFSO.FileExists("DecodeMe.vbs") Then
Ws.Run "DecodeMe.vbs",True
End If
Sleep 2000
If objFSO.FileExists("DecodedFile.txt") Then
Set Readme = objFso.OpenTextFile("DecodedFile.txt",1)
LireTout = Readme.ReadAll
txtBody.value = LireTout
End if
End Sub

Sub Sleep(MSecs) 
 Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  If Fso.FileExists("sleeper.vbs")=False Then
  Set objOutputFile = fso.CreateTextFile("sleeper.vbs", True)
  objOutputFile.Write "wscript.sleep WScript.Arguments(0)"
  objOutputFile.Close
  End If
 CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "sleeper.vbs " & MSecs,1 , True
 End Sub

Function qq(strIn)
    qq = Chr(34) & strIn & Chr(34)
End Function

Sub VBEDecode()
Dim NomFichier
NomFichier = file1.value
If NomFichier<>"" Then
    Dim fso
    Set fso=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If fso.FileExists(NomFichier) Then
        Dim fic,contenu
        Set fic = fso.OpenTextFile(NomFichier, 1)
        Contenu=fic.readAll
        fic.close
        Set fic=Nothing

        Const TagInit="#@~^" '#@~^awQAAA==
        Const TagFin="==^#~@" '& chr(0)
        Dim DebutCode, FinCode
        Do
            FinCode=0
            DebutCode=Instr(Contenu,TagInit)
            If DebutCode>0 Then
                If (Instr(DebutCode,Contenu,"==")-DebutCode)=10 Then 'If "==" follows the tag
                    FinCode=Instr(DebutCode,Contenu,TagFin)
                    If FinCode>0 Then
                        Contenu=Left(Contenu,DebutCode-1) & _
                        Decode(Mid(Contenu,DebutCode+12,FinCode-DebutCode-12-6)) & _
                        Mid(Contenu,FinCode+6)
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Loop Until FinCode=0
   Set f = fso.OpenTextFile(NomFichier &"_Decodee.txt",2,true)
   f.writeLine contenu
   If  fso.FileExists(NomFichier &"_Decodee.txt") Then

        Set fic = fso.OpenTextFile(NomFichier &"_Decodee.txt", 1)
        Contenu=fic.ReadAll
        txtBody.value = Contenu
        fic.Close

        Set fic=Nothing
    End if  
    Else
        MsgBox NomFichier & " not found"
    End If
    Set fso=Nothing
Else
MsgBox "ATTENTION ! ! ! ! ! !" & vbcr & "Le fichier n'existe pas ? " & vbcr &_
 "Veuillez SVP choisir un fichier !",48,"Le Fichier n'existe pas ? "
End If
End Sub
Function Decode(Chaine)
    Dim se,i,c,j,index,ChaineTemp
    Dim tDecode(127)
    Const Combinaison="1231232332321323132311233213233211323231311231321323112331123132" 

    Set se=CreateObject("Scripting.Encoder")
    For i=9 to 127
        tDecode(i)="JLA"
    Next
    For i=9 to 127
        ChaineTemp=Mid(se.EncodeScriptFile(".vbs",string(3,i),0,""),13,3)
        For j=1 to 3
            c=Asc(Mid(ChaineTemp,j,1))
            tDecode(c)=Left(tDecode(c),j-1) & chr(i) & Mid(tDecode(c),j+1)
        Next
    Next
    'Next line we correct a bug, otherwise a ")" could be decoded to a ">"
    tDecode(42)=Left(tDecode(42),1) & ")" & Right(tDecode(42),1)
    Set se=Nothing 

    Chaine=Replace(Replace(Chaine,"@&",chr(10)),"@#",chr(13))
    Chaine=Replace(Replace(Chaine,"@*",">"),"@!","<")
    Chaine=Replace(Chaine,"@$","@")
    index=-1
    For i=1 to Len(Chaine)
        c=asc(Mid(Chaine,i,1))
        If c<128 Then index=index+1
        If (c=9) or ((c>31) and (c<128)) Then
            If (c<>60) and (c<>62) and (c<>64) Then
                Chaine=Left(Chaine,i-1) & Mid(tDecode(c),Mid(Combinaison,(index mod 64)+1,1),1) & Mid(Chaine,i+1)
            End If
        End If
    Next
    Decode=Chaine
End Function

Sub EncoderVBE()
Set scrEnc = CreateObject("Scripting.Encoder")
Set scrFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
MonFichier = file1.value
If MonFichier = "" Then
MsgBox "ATTENTION ! ! ! ! ! !" & vbcr & "Le fichier n'existe pas ? " & vbcr &_
 "Veuillez SVP choisir un fichier !",48,"Le Fichier n'existe pas ? "
 Exit Sub
End If 
    myfile = scrFSO.OpenTextFile(MonFichier).ReadAll
    If scrFSO.FileExists(MonFichier&"_encode.vbe") Then scrFSO.DeleteFile MonFichier&"_encode.vbe", True
    myFileEncode=scrENC.EncodeScriptFile(".vbs", myfile, 0, "")
    Set ts = scrFSO.CreateTextFile(MonFichier&"_encode.vbe.txt", True, False)
    ts.Write myFileEncode
ts.Close
Set fic = scrFSO.OpenTextFile(MonFichier&"_encode.vbe.txt", 1)
        Contenu=fic.ReadAll
        txtBody.value = Contenu
        fic.Close
End Sub

</script>
<center><body BGCOLOR="#000000" TOPMARGIN="10" LEFTMARGIN="10">
<label>Fichier à parcourir....  </label><input type="file" name="file1" id="file1" /><br>
<label>Résultat de la Conversion:</label><br/>
<textarea id="txtBody" rows="30" cols="150"></textarea><br><br>
<input type="button" style="width: 140px" value="Encoder le Fichier" onclick="EncoderVBE">
<input type="button" style="width: 140px" value="Decoder le Fichier" onclick="VBEDecode">
<input type="button" style="width: 100px" value="Sortir" onclick="OnClickButtonCancel">
</td></tr>
</table>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hackoo This is really great and usefull tool! I think I should specify my question. I have created a vbs script. In order to protect it- I encoded it into vbe. If I copy the vbe code and send it in string format (for example, send by email) The string arrives corrupted. How should I handle the code so that I could safely send to other source? Great thanx in advance!