# vbscript encoded file (vbe) not properly working after adding plain vbs

Tags: vbscript

I have encoded vbs(vbe) and  plain vbs in one file (.vbe) I create this file programmatically with the help of other .vbs script.
For some reason, when it is created programmatically- (.vbe) file doesnt work. BUT When I open it in notepad and add just a simple space, save it and run again- vbe works perfectly. What can be the reason for that?

Also if I manually copy the code from the opened .vbe and then create in ANSI format new .vbe and paste there my code- it works also as well

Comment: Take a look at this  ==> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32882622/convert-vbs-encrypted-script-to-string/32882934#32882934

Comment: Might be an encoding problem. Saving it in a text editor can possibly change the encoding (although it shouldn't). If the original file is UTF-8 wscript cannot read it iirc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert vbs encrypted script to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32882622/convert-vbs-encrypted-script-to-string)